# Jinja2 entry in a for loop

Tags: python, jinja2, keras

I am currently getting an error trying to do this

```
kernel_number = [{choice{80,100,120,140,160,180,200}} for i in range(splits)]
```

I want each entry in the list to have `{choice{80,100,120,140,160,180,200}}`

its a jinja2 style parameter which is provided as parameter to ones NN layer in keras according to [this](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas)

Error being invalid syntax

About the 2 x {} according to example code on GitHub, it has to be like that. 
Why is this is not possible?

Comment: What error are you getting? btw there is one `{` and two `}`

Comment: @tiwo I see 2 `{` and 2 `}`

Comment: :-) ah now I see both :-D

Comment: Ahh.. I made a mistake.. It should have been `[{{choice([80,100,120,140,160,180,200])}}]`